# How to resize the google map according to existing the markers in android programming ?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, resize, google-maps-api-2

In my application,different clients  are trying to enter the server system and server take the locations of  those clients  and set them into google map.However,I do not want  to zoom the map by manual  to see the locations of clients in detail.I want to  resize the  map  according to existing  markers because clients see their location on the map after a while.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a LatLngBound for all your markers and then zoom to it:

```
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(getBoundingBox(), 50));
```

Where:

```
LatLngBounds getBoundingBox() {
        final List<Marker> markers ... //you have to already provide the list of available marker somewhere
        //Now zoom to point!
        LatLngBounds.Builder llBuilder = LatLngBounds.builder();
        for (Marker _point : markers) {
            llBuilder.include(_point.getPosition());
        }
        return llBuilder.build();
    }
```

Comment: You are welcome, if it helps and answer to your question, you can accept and vote the answer ;)